# Android CirclePageIndicator not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

Im not able to load the page with circlepageindicator. This is the xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/bg2" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="32dp" android:layout_marginTop="32dp">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager" />   

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

java file

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MyPagerAdapter adapter=new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(2);

    CirclePageIndicator titleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    titleIndicator.setViewPager(myPager);
}
```

jake wharton project has been added to the library. It doesnt give any error while building, but not loading the page. whats wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `ViewPager` is set to `match_parent` which will prevent any other view in the container from showing. Set the `ViewPager` height to `0dp` with `android:layout_weight="1"`.

The container is also hard-coded to `32dp` which is extremely tiny and likely will not hold both the pager and indicator comfortably.

Comment: its not that the circlepageindicator is missing, the page itself is not loading. Again it 'stopped unexpectedly'.

Comment: I've added ur library project in java buildpath. But still the circlepageindicator is shown in greybox in design of xml.

Comment: You have to add it as a library project under the 'Android' settings and not through the Java build path.

Comment: thanks jake, it worked. My mistake was isLibrary was not checked. Also i had to comment a few methods like fakedrag, it shows - doesnt belong to viewpager class. 
Now i need to add theme to indicators, but it doesnt take the app:radius,... also tried with style, it doesnt take except for android:...

Comment: If you didn't have those methods you're using an old version of the support library. Use the SDK Manager to upgrade.

Comment: @JakeWharton how to add drawable{image} to circlepage indicator. If i use iconpageindictor onclick method is not working.

Comment: @JakeWharton , Question : Can we stop circle from flowing from one indicator to another indicator?

Answer (score 3):

Missing to add `myIndicator.onPageScrolled(myViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0, 0);` may also cause CirclePageIndicator not working.

eg: `myViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                myIndicator.onPageScrolled(myViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0, 0);
            }
        });`